# angularjs how to put array in my url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

im getting multiple month in my url here my problem i get of object instead of a name of the months that i choose

[image]

as you can see in my url i got object **months=%5Bobject%20Object%5D**

i want to see like this months = [mar, apr]

here my view in that particular combobox

```
md-input-container flex=""
      label Months
      md-select ng-model="params.months[month]" multiple="true"
        md-option ng-repeat="month in ctrl.months "  ng-value="month"
          | {{month}}
```

here my controller

```
#= require ./../../module

class IncomeStatementIndexCtrl
  constructor: ($scope, $route, $mdDialog, $filter, $routeParams, $location, Account, Branch)->
    @branches = Branch.query()
    @clear = ->
      $scope.params = {}
      $location.search($scope.params)

    $scope.params = $location.search()

    @months = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 
    'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

   if $scope.params.as_of_date?
     $scope.params.as_of_date = new Date($scope.params.as_of_date)
     @incomes = Account::IncomeStatement.query ($scope.params), (data) =>


   @search = () =>
     $scope.params.date_to_compare = 
     $filter('date'($scope.params.date_to_compare , "yyyy-MM-dd")
     $scope.params.as_of_date = $filter('date')
    ($scope.params.as_of_date , "yyyy-MM-dd")
     $location.search($scope.params)



IncomeStatementIndexCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$route", "$mdDialog", "$filter", "$routeParams", "$location", "Account", "Branch"]

angular
  .module "CaesApp"
  .controller "IncomeStatementIndexCtrl", IncomeStatementIndexCtrl
```

i need to achieve this so i can get correct the params in my controller in ruby on rails

Comment: to send params as array, what you need to do in cross browser way is.. `?month=mar&month=apr&mon=may`, you will need to write custom code or use some library to `convert array to urlEncode format`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much angular, but for send array on any request is :

```
request =  url?parameter[]=a&parameter[]=b&parameter[]=c
```

and on rails it is

```
"parameter":[
"a","b","c"
]
```

Comment: hi @Darlyncinho Bravo any plunker or jsfiddle so i can visualize thanks for the reply T_T